# How to read and predict images outside the dataset using the knn algorithm

Tags: python, algorithm, google-colaboratory, knn

[I have difficulty in an algorithm knn, how can I predict a new image outside of the dataset I'm using? how is the coding?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rhpni.png)

I have difficulty in an algorithm knn, how can I predict a new image outside of the dataset I'm using? how is the coding?

Comment: Please avoid using a screenshot of code in a question. It makes it harder to help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this example code to to read your images.

```
from io import BytesIO
import numpy as np
import requests
from PIL import Image

response = requests.get(url)
img = Image.open(BytesIO(response.content))
img = np.array(img).reshape(1, -1)
output_class = neigh.predict(img)[0]
print(output_class)
```